# A Finite State Machine with Polymorphic Types?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I want to create a finite state machine where ...

Things of type A may transition to B, C, or D, and things of B, C, or D may only transition back to A. They can transition to any of the other states, but only via A.

I want the Scala compiler to help me out, and provide me with some sugar via an Ops class, but I'm getting a lovely, useful "not available" error.

Any advice, StackOverflow?

```
// let's start with some coproducts
sealed trait Color
trait Red extends Color
trait Blue extends Color

// define a car whose behavior should, for this
// example, be a function of the color of the car
final case class Car[A](make: String, model: String)

trait Paintshop[C[_], From, To] {
  def paint(car: C[From]): C[To]
}

object Paintshop {
  implicit val redCarsCanBePaintedBlue = new Paintshop[Car, Red, Blue] {
    override def paint(car: Car[Red]): Car[Blue] = Car[Blue](car.make, car.model)
  }
}

object CarOps {
  implicit class CarOps(car: Car[Red]) {
    def paint(implicit P: Paintshop[Car, Red, Blue]): Car[Blue] = P.paint(car)
  }
}

// now to make the magic happen
// let's paint a Red Car Blue
import CarOps._
val car = Car[Red]("Honda", "Civic").paint[Blue]
```

alas; `.paint` is not available for `Car[Red]`! pourquoi?

Comment: Should I manipulate the color via a property on the case class instead? If so, how do I then ask the compiler other questions about what I can do with red and blue cars, respectively?

Comment: Method `paint` do not have generic parameters.

Comment: You can imagine `paint` with generic parameters and this code will still fail. This was a mistranscription on my part, from my actual code. I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have `object` and `implicit class` with same name.

Rename `implicit class CarOps` to `implicit class CarOpsX` and it will be successfully compiled.

Comment: Ah; this explains some of the code from FP for Mortals, and why Simulacra generates ops classes as it does. Late night. Thank you!